# Speed up or turn off SVN cache update in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn

Every time I open my eclipse it takes a lot of time (30 to 60 min)to update svn cache. So could you please tell,  Is there any way I can speed up or turn off the svn cache update?

If I turn off the svn cache update, what will be effect?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "update svn cache". Subversion itself does not need to update any cache on client-side and it should never take so much time as you describe.

Comment: I believe this is an Eclipse-specific feature, [detailed here](https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_performance.php).

Answer (score 7):

I noticed this taking awhile on my machine running Eclipse Neon so I disabled the `Compute deep outgoing state` option under `Window` > `Preferences` > `Team` > `SVN` > `Performance`.  This has helped considerably with no obvious detrimental effect.  Note that I left the `Enable SVN statuses cache` option on.

[Eclipse Subversive - Documentation - Performance](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_performance.php)