# How to manage non-code files (docs, etc.) with Eclipse and Subversive SVN?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm working with Eclipse (assume the latest version) and the Subversive SVN plugin. My SVN structure is the typical one:

- branches
- docs

  - ...
- tags
- trunk

  - scripts
  - project1

    - src...
    - pom.xml
  - project2
  - ...

I have checked out the whole structure using TortoiseSVN, and have imported in Eclipse project1, project2, etc. So when I want to commit or download code changes, I just do it from Eclipse. If I want to do the same with the documents or SQL scripts (which are outside the projects), I have to use TortoiseSVN instead. The problem is, [TortoiseSVN and Subclipse don't work well together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226943/how-can-i-prevent-tortoisesvn-database-locking-up).

If I want to have those folders inside Eclipse to manage them with Subversive... how should I do it? Surely there has to be a better way than creating an empty "general" project, right?

Comment: PS: sorry if it's a really dumb question. I tried searching before asking, but I didn't come up with good search terms for this one...

Comment: Do not mix [simple and standard layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/108682/6505250): `docs` should not be on the same level as `branches`, `tags` and `trunk`.

Comment: To answer your question: in Eclipse only a project (not a folder) can be shared via SVN as the information of the repository is stored on project level.